# Spring security fails when there are static file mappings in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml-2.0

I am using Spring SAML with OKTA and JSF.
When I add any servlet mapping for static file I don't see that `org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter` is ever executed, even on /saml/SSO page, after I am redirected from OKTA. I got 404 form my application and that is all.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I remove this entries I am redirected to on "succes page". I tried to remove this files from spring security, but it doesn't help.

```
<security:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/resources/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/logout.jsp"/>
```

There is no exceptions, authorization looks OK, but when I load any secured page I got redirected to /saml/SSO. Then I would expect that I will be redirected by `authenticationSuccessHandler`, but nothing happens.

**WEB.XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- omega, redmond -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>omega</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- SSO -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/security/securityContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- LOG4j -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- PRIMEFACES -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- <filter-mapping> <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name> 
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> </filter-mapping> -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/error/viewExpired.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error/404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>faces-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>faces-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- default mappings -->

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
    [ images and others ...]
</web-app>
```

**SPRING LOG :**

```
18:23:23.496 [http-apr-80-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.s.c.SAMLContextProviderImpl - No IDP specified, using default http://www.okta.com/exk6fkmm7e84LEY4W0h7
18:23:23.496 [http-apr-80-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil - Index for AssertionConsumerService not specified, returning default
18:23:23.496 [http-apr-80-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint - Processing SSO using WebSSO profile
18:23:23.497 [http-apr-80-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl - Using default consumer service with binding urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
18:23:23.524 [http-apr-80-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.saml.util.SLF4JLogChute - ResourceManager : found /templates/saml2-post-binding.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
18:23:23.524 [http-apr-80-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.saml.util.SLF4JLogChute - ResourceManager : found /templates/add-html-head-content.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
18:23:23.525 [http-apr-80-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.saml.util.SLF4JLogChute - ResourceManager : found /templates/add-html-body-content.vm with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
18:23:23.525 [http-apr-80-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.s.storage.HttpSessionStorage - Storing message a4c93jc724eg7e2f25i81c6a80hb481 to session D29095A9F7579F9357419777D414EE2E
18:23:23.525 [http-apr-80-exec-10] INFO  o.s.s.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger - AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;127.0.0.1;http://trucksapp:80/saml/metadata;http://www.okta.com/exk6fkmm7e84LEY4W0h7;;;
```